# I accidentally installed whereami on my EC2 instance (ubuntu) now I can't ssh into machine

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2

I misunderstood what this command does I believe. I thought it just told you the hostname, but apparently it tries to make changes to your networking configuration as well. Is there anything I can do to get back into the machine and remove whereami?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the same. So I changed **managed=false** to **managed=true** in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf.

---

And then:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

It helpls me to get things work again, but you have to connect directly somehow not over ssh.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up restoring from a backup because I could not physically get into the machine.

Answer (score 3):

> The Debian version of whereami is designed to provide multiple network connectivity options for laptops or other portable devices capable of running Debian/Ubuntu Linux. The functionality of whereami for Debian-based Linux distributions is completely different from the functionality of whereami provided for Enterprise versions of Linux such as Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Amazon Linux, and enterprise versions of SuSe or Centos Linux. Attempted installation of the whereami package on an Amazon EC2 Debian/Ubuntu Linux instance will terminate any existing connection to the instance and cause all future connection attempts to fail. Note: attempts to install whereami on an Amazon EC2 Debian/Ubuntu Linux instance encounter problems running dpkg-reconfigure, causing the installation to hang and eventually fail.

[Here's detailed guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-ubuntu-whereami/) from Amazon of how to restore network connectivity to an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu Linux instance after installing whereami:

1. Start an Amazon EC2 Linux ‘rescue’ instance with chroot installed.
2. Stop the Debian/Ubuntu EC2 instance.
3. Detach the root volume of the Debian/Ubuntu EC2 instance.
4. Attach the root volume of the Debian/Ubuntu EC2 instance to the Amazon EC2 ‘rescue’ instance.
5. Start the ‘rescue’ instance if it is not already started, and open a terminal session.
6. Run the following command to mount the root volume from the Debian/Ubuntu instance to /mnt: `sudo mount /dev/xvdf /mnt`
7. Run the following command to chroot into the root volume of the Debian/Ubuntu instance: `chroot /mnt /bin/bash`
8. Run the following command to remove the whereami package from the Debian/Ubuntu instance. `apt-get remove --purge whereami`
9. Run the following command to unmount the root volume of the Debian/Ubuntu instance and remove from the rescue instance. `exit;umount /mnt;`
10. After the disk is unmounted, detach the root volume of the Debian/Ubuntu EC2 instance from the ‘rescue’ instance.
11. Reattach the root volume of the Debian/Ubuntu EC2 instance.
12. Start the Debian/Ubuntu EC2 instance. Network connectivity should be restored and connections to the instance should be successful.